# How to return a variable from .getText in nightwatch?

Tags: javascript, nightwatch.js

I have a function `.getText` from which I need to return a variable `num3` to compare it on the following pages. But the assert at the end is failing because num3 is "undefined".

```
var num3;
... 
.getText('my_selector', function(result) {
                const num = (number * result.value) * 0.05;
                const num2 = (number * result.value) - num;
                num3 = Math.round(num2 * 100) / 100;

this.expect.element('my_selector').to.have.value.equal(num3); })
...
.assert.containsText('my_selector2', num3) //undefined
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution for this problem. We need the .perform function. http://nightwatchjs.org/api#perform

```
var num3;
... 
.getText('my_selector', function(result) {
            const num = (number * result.value) * 0.05;
            const num2 = (number * result.value) - num;
            num3 = Math.round(num2 * 100) / 100;

this.expect.element('my_selector').to.have.value.equal(num3); })
...
.perform( function(){
          this.api
              .useXpath()//it's necessary if you use Xpath selector
              .assert.containsText('my_selector2', num3)
            })
```

For more on why this is necessary, read up on the [Nightwatch command queue](https://github.com/nightwatchjs/nightwatch/wiki/Understanding-the-Command-Queue).